# CreateBrowserHistory throttling causes browser to slow down the speed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am working on a React JS project.
I am also using the `react-router-dom` for routing.

While accessing the web pages I noticed that my browser was getting slow down, upon checking the console area I found this message.

```
Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging. (anonymous) @ createBrowserHistory.js?6e99:211
```

This error is pointing to `createBrowserHistory.js?6e99:211` file.
Earlier I thought this is a browser issue but it is coming from my react project.

I got no solution when I googled it.
Anyone ever came across this issue while working with `React JS`.

Is there any possibility that, I am calling a lot of actions and for every action the `react` components are re-rendered and this is causing the issue.

**AppRouter.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';

import HomePage from './../components/HomePage';
import AboutUs from './../components/AboutUs';
import ContactUs from './../components/ContactUs';
import PageNotFound from './../components/PageNotFound';
import RestaurantList from '../components/RestaurantList';
import RestaurantMenu from '../components/RestaurantMenu';
import UserDetails from '../components/UserDetails';
import OrderConfirmation from '../components/OrderConfirmation';
import CustomerAccount from '../components/CustomerAccount';

export default () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route render={({location}) => (
                <TransitionGroup>
                    <CSSTransition key={location.key} timeout={300} classNames="fade">
                        <Switch location={location}>
                            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true}/>
                            <Route path="/about" component={AboutUs} />
                            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactUs} />
                            <Route path="/restaurants" component={RestaurantList} />
                            <Route path="/select-menu" component={RestaurantMenu} />
                            <Route path="/user-details" component={UserDetails} />
                            <Route path="/order-confirmation" component={OrderConfirmation} />
                            <Route path="/my-account" component={CustomerAccount} />
                            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                        </Switch>
                    </CSSTransition>
                </TransitionGroup>
            )} />

        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: What does your routing look like?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What happens when you remove `TransitionGroup` and `CSSTransition`?

Comment: I was getting the same error in my project and in my case I had a div under the Router. I replaced that with Router > Switch and then all the routes underneath. And that solved the problem. I hope it helps you.